# Can not view the text of the parent tab when selecting child tab

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to display simple drop down with two colours(Black and White). When I have selected child tab I could not see anything in the parent tab. Please check out the Tab1 and Tab3.

In Tab3, If i have selected the grand child, I could not get select view any of my parent. My code is below.

**CSS FILE :**

```
*   { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body    { font: 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; } 
#page-wrap  { width: 800px; margin: 25px auto; } 
a   { text-decoration: none; }
ul  { list-style: none; }
p   { margin: 15px 0; }

label {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ui-custom-calender-icon {
    background: url("images/calender_icon.png") no-repeat #ECECED;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px!important;
    border-radius:  2px!important;
}

/* 
 *  LEVEL ONE
 */
ul.dropdown { position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li      { font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; background: #505050;}
ul.dropdown a:hover { color: #505050; }
ul.dropdown a:active    { color: #505050; }
ul.dropdown li a    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;color: #ffffff; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover    { color: #505050;background: #ffffff;  position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a  { color: #ffffff; background: #505050;}

/* 
 *  LEVEL TWO
 */
ul.dropdown ul      { width: 220px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; background: #505050;}
ul.dropdown ul li       { font-weight: normal; background: #505050; color: #505050;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; float: none; }

/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a     { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; } 

/* 
 *  LEVEL THREE
 */
ul.dropdown ul ul       { left: 100%; top: 0; }
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul   { visibility: visible; }
```

**HTML FILE :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> My Custom MenuBar </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="menubar">
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">TAB 1</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">CHILD 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CHILD 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CHILD 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CHILD 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">TAB 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TAB 3</a>
                            <ul class="sub_menu">
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="">CHILD 1</a>
                                    <ul clas="sub_menu">
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick="">GRAND CHILD 1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dropdownPlain.js" defer="defer"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from from your following line of css code:

```
ul.dropdown li a { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; color: #ffffff; }
```

Here it is mentioned text color to be 'white' on hover, which works well. Until the hover state changes from 'tab#' element to its any of child element or dropdown menu item. Since the current hovered item is changed, your following other line of css code applies:

```
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover  { color: #505050;background: #ffffff;  position: relative; }
```

Which is changing any 'li' background color to white. And now at this point both of your background and text color are white, so your parent element text is not visible.

---

**Update:**

following css should resolve your issue:

```
ul.dropdown li:hover { color: #ffffff; background: red; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li:hover a { color: #ffffff; }
*change background color from red to anyother of your choice, but not to white :)
```

It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uHC8D/2/)

Edited first four lines

```
 ul.dropdown    { position: relative; }
    ul.dropdown li      { font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; background: #505050; position: relative; }
    ul.dropdown li a    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; }
```

Comment: You could check the following link. It is my problem http://jsfiddle.net/uHC8D/1/

Comment: Please check my fiddle now